# Is this version of clustering still NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, clustering

Let the set $A = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$ of objects and $d(a_i,aj) \quad \forall i,j\in[n] \quad i\neq j$.
Let $\;C=\{C_1,...,C_k\}$ the set of clusters, split the elements of $A$ into $C$ such as there is not $C_i$ empty.

We need to maximaze the distance between clusters which is the minimum  distance between all the elements of different clusters.

$$max_{\{C_1,...C_k\}}\ \{min_{x_i \in X} \{{min_{x_j \notin C(x_i)}}\; d(x_i,x_j))\}\} $$ where $C(x_i)$ is the cluster of $x_i$ and $\{C_1,...C_k\}$ are all the possible partitions of $C$

I think the problem above is a simplification of [K-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), is there any differences?

Comment: Could you write the objective function to be minimized?